# Getting solution path in a T4 template via MSBuild property

Tags: c#, msbuild, t4

What is the best way to get the current solution's full path from within a T4 template? What I currently have is:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ output extension=".g.cs" #>

<#= "//" + this.DTE.Solution.FileName #>

<#+
private DTE dte;

private DTE DTE
{
    get
    {
        if (this.dte == null)
        {
            var hostServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider)Host;
            this.dte = (DTE)hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
        }

        return this.dte;
    }
}
#>
```

This works, but I have some concerns:

- it ties me to the DTE/COM layer, which I have found to be a source of many problems
- I must have a host-specific template, which limits future flexibility
- the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionclass.aspx) for `SolutionClass` states that the various properties are infrastructual and for Microsoft's use only

I was hoping to find a way to use the MSBuild `$(SolutionPath)` property. Even though it's still somewhat to VS and won't work if generating within MSBuild, it would at least be cleaner. However, I couldn't find a way to use any MSBuild property from within a T4 template control block.

For example, this works:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Foo.dll" #>
```

But this does not:

```
<# WriteLine("$(ProjectDir)"); #>
```

Obviously the property needs to be escaped in some manner, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to achieve this.

Comment: According to the documentation you have to define a `project property` instead. See: [Using project properties in MSBuild and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949.aspx)

Comment: @I'L'I: regardless of how the property is defined, there's no way I can find to actually obtain its value within a template control block (see question).

Comment: FWIW It may be the escaping as you mentioned. I've seen `Host.ResolvePath` using `"\\"` instead of `"//"` before, so maybe try `<#= "\\" + ...`

Comment: I looked at t4 templating and found it extremely difficult to use  so instead I went with dotliquid. It is open source with quite a few tests/examples that made it super simple to use. http://dotliquidmarkup.org/ I am usually a big fan of MSFT but this time the open source community may have gotten it done a little better.